# Infinite loop possible in laying out html?

Tags: html, layout

How many layout passes are required when laying html elements when the heights of child elements are specified as a percentage of their parents, which don't specify an explicit height? For instance in the case of

```
<div>
  <div style:"height=50%">...</div>      
  ...
</div>
```

the height of the inner div ("50% of parent's height") can not be immediately computed, since the height of the parent is not known until all of its children's heights are summed up. But that in turn requires laying out the children, including computing the height of the inner div... Seems like an infinite loop scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At most 2 recursion cycles:

1. a bottom-up cycle on which you ask the elements "assume you are not height-constrained, which would be your *minimum* hight?" (within your width constraints).

   - leafs will report their minimum
   - parents will look at their children minimum, compute its own minimal height based on the percentage each child is assigned and the reported minimal height.
2. a top-down cycle in which, based on the reported minimum heights, you compute **and set** the actual heights which obey the proportions.

This way, the minimal height elements (the leafs) will determine the actual heigh at the end for every node.

---

Question in comment:

> What's the exact way that parents will compute its own minimal height based on percentage each child specifies and what each child reports as its minimal height?

Oh, come on! If one child is prescribed a percentage of `p` and reports a minimum height of `m`, what is the total minimal total height required to satisfy that child? Let's put it as at the primary school: if `p%` represents `m`, how much is `100%`?

Assume children {c<sub>1</sub>, ... , c<sub>M</sub>} with required percentages of {p<sub>1</sub>, ... , p<sub>M</sub>} (all percentages > 0, otherwise just ignore the children, they'll have their height to 0 by definition) and reporting {m<sub>1</sub>, ... , m<sub>M</sub>} as minimum heights.

The minimal height for the parent is Hp=max(m<sub>1</sub> / p<sub>1</sub>, ...,  m<sub>N</sub> / p<sub>N</sub>) and the children are to be scaled to {p<sub>1</sub>*H<sub>p</sub>, ... , p<sub>M</sub>**H<sub>p</sub>} respectively *after the "negotiation" of the actual height*

Comment: What's the exact way that parents will compute its own minimal height based on percentage each child specifies and what each child reports as its minimal height?

Comment: Yeah, but that assumes _all_ children specify their height as percentages (since then you can set the parent height as anything, which is why you can use minimums). But let's say one child specifies 50% height of parent and a minimum height of 200, and another child specifies an _absolute_ height of 70. (html for this might be <div> <div height=50%></div> <div height=70px></div></div>). Then there is no way to satisfy these constraints :  {h_div1 = .5 h_total  ,  h_div1 + 70 = h_total , h_div1 > 200 }   [solving the first two equations for h_div1  gives h_div1 = 70]

Comment: @user98235 And HTML doesn't automatically satisfy impossible constraints - check for yourself. But I guarantee, weird as it may seen,  you at max 2 passes are done  on the height dimension.